# Unable to activate Workspaces ccsm / dash / dconf ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, 13.04, compiz, unity-dash, workspaces

I ran the latest updates and as usual I had to re-install my video driver, download the headers and blah blah...

I ran into a few troubles that I was able to fix and at the end I got my Ubuntu up and running, Unity working, OpenGl working without a single problem... games running fine but wait.

I have only 1 worspace !  oooh no problem, lets ccsm to fix that... nope it has no effect. Well, we can activate the workspaces on dash --> Appearance... nope, nothing happends.

Oooooh yea, the dconf editor !!  I will force those workspaces thru that method aaaaaand  :/ nothing once again.  :(

Maybe im missing something, maybe I missed something in this forum... but I cant find a way to fix those worspaces. I can only have 1 and thats it.

Does anyone had thtis problem before?
Can I has my workspaces back? I only need 4  :(

Comment: I forgot to point out the fact that if I change the icon size inside appearance window... same result; nothing happends.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my workspaces back :D

Solution is:

1.- Export your compiz config thru ccsm (if you lack of it just sudo apt-get install ccsm).
2.- Find the [core] section.
3.- Set the amount of workspaces with:

```
s0_hsize = 2
s0_vsize = 2
```

4.- Import your config back to compiz.
5.- Enjoy your workspaces.

This has to be done this way because ccsm lacks of some settings... this is one of them.